Wix4 + docker sdk
We are building our .csproj using mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
We need also to build a .wixproj but the dotnet build gives us
wix.exe : error WIX0001: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'msi.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (0x8007007E) [C:\src\xxx\yyy.Setup.wixproj]
Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

That docker image is based on Linux which doesn't support MSI which WiX needs. Try 6.0-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 or 4.8-20240312-windowsservercore-ltsc2022 instead.
